# Firefox unable to load google.com after leaving computer with firefox open for several hours

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I leave my home computer on all day, with firefox sitting open. I'll usually have many tabs open, youtube, gmail, etc.  A  cable provider is my ISP.

Sometimes when I come back after a day of work I find firefox is unable to connect to any google domain, until I open chrome. I can browse reddit or wikipedia or any site that doesn't involve a google domain just fine, but once I try to perform google search, or am loading a site that connects to google for some ad data, the browser doesn't get anywhere (just waiting for some google domain).

Upon opening chrome and loading google.com, firefox is then able to load pages from google without any problem.

I am running firefox version 25. I haven't tried disabling extensions yet.  What could be going wrong with firefox?  Anything I could do to find out more?

Comment: Try changing your DNS provider.

Comment: Try reading the instructions at www.opendns.com or https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Comment: Cool question. I am curious to see what will happen if you change your DNS provider to Google DNS. Try the link Peter gave you, and let us know if it worked or not :)

You can also try to clean all caches etc from Firefox. Maybe there's just something wrong with your cache that prevents Google from being loaded.

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding, it seems to work!  i notice that this problem with firefox being unable to access google happens even with a linux live boot USB, freshly loaded, so there is something weird about firefox and our default dns servers.  thanks for the help!